# ¿Cómo obtengo la causa de Storage::put esté devolviendo false?

Tags: php, laravel, filesystem

Estoy tratando de guardar una imagen, cuando la guardo localmente, devuelve "verdadero", pero en otro disco devuelve "falso". ¿Es posible recuperar la causa por la que devuelve "falso"?

```php
        $ImgSource = (string) Image::make($this->photo)->encode('jpg', 75);

        $local = Storage::put($path, $ImgSource); //return true
        $update = Storage::disk('mycloud')->put($path, $ImgSource); //return false
```

Aclaro que ya he subido archivos de texto y otras imágenes, pero con algunos archivos tengo este problema y mi intención es encontrar la causa del error.

driver owncloud disk:
https://github.com/F4brizio/laravel-owncloud
https://github.com/F4brizio/flysystem-owncloud

Comment: Has probado a mirar  en "storage/logs/laravel.log" a ver si muestra el error?

Comment: Estoy notando que en disco **local** usas `temp/file.jpg` para la ruta en donde guardar, pero en el otro disco, usas `$path` ¿cual es el valor de esa variable `$path`? esa puede ser la causa del problema, tal vez

Comment: Lo use solo como prueba, de igual forma también lo use con $path y funciona perfectamente cuando se trata del local.

Comment: Entonces si sigue fallando, tiene que ser la configuración del disco ¿Puedes colocarla por favor? y especificar que **driver** estas usando

Comment: Listo, lo coloque al final de la pregunta. laravel-owncloud que a su vez usa flysystem-owncloud. (Intento encontrar el problema para poder corregirlo desde el driver.)

Comment: Dos posibles causas: 1. La ruta no existe 2. La carpeta no tiene permisos de escritura para el usuario bajo el que se ejecuta el servidor